# Einstein summation for matricized tensor times Khatri Rao product (mttkrp) for use in tensor decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, tensors, tensor-decomposition, einstein-notation

I am trying to compute the matricized tensor times Khatri-Rao product (mttkrp) as part of an optimization problem for tensor factorization, shown below:

$A = \mathcal{X}_{(1)}(B \otimes C)$

Where $\mathcal{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{L \times M \times N} $ is a tensor, $B \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times R}$ and $C \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times R}$ are (factor) matrices and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{L \times R}$. The subscript $\mathcal{X}_{(1)}$ indicates the i-th mode unfolding of a tensor (matricization where the mode-i fibers become the columns of the resulting matrix) and $\otimes$ is the Khatri-Rao product. The mttkrp is the most expensive operation in my problem, so often a mttkrp kernel is used in place of this direct computation, shown in index notation:

$A_{i,j} = \sum_{k,l} \mathcal{X}_{i,k,l}  B_{k,j} C_{l,j}$

What I need actually need to compute is the mttkrp of matrices in reverse:

$D = \mathcal{X}_{(1)}(C \otimes B)$.

$D \in \mathbb{R}^{L \times R}$. I would like to know if anyone knows how to formulate this in Einstein summation?

EDIT:
I have seen it reported several times in literature/software documentation that the index notation expression for $D$ is (e.g., [Kjolstad et al](http://fredrikbk.com/publications/taco-workspaces.pdf)):

$D_{i,j} = \sum_{k,l} \mathcal{X}_{i,k,l}  C_{l,j} B_{k,j}$

However, I am unable to reproduce/program this. See associated python code for the comparison of direct matrix multiplication vs associated kernels.

```
    import numpy as np
    from tensorly.tenalg import khatri_rao
    from tensorly.base import unfold
    
    L,M,N,R = 10,20,15,3
    X = np.random.randn(L,M,N)
    B = np.random.randn(M,R)
    C = np.random.randn(N,R)
    
    p1 = np.dot(unfold(X,0),khatri_rao([B,C])) # forward
    p2 = np.dot(unfold(X,0),khatri_rao([C,B])) # reverse
    p3 = np.einsum('ikl,kj,lj->ij',X,B,C) # forward
    np.allclose(p1,p3) # True
    p4 = np.einsum('ilk,kj,lj->ij',X,C,B) # proposed kernel
    np.allclose(p2,p4) # False
    np.allclose(p1,p4) # True
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on the unfolding here? It sounds like $\mathcal X_{(1)}$ will have $L$ rows and $MN$ columns, is that correct? If so, then what exactly is the ordering of the $MN$ mode-1 fibers? Do we take $\mathcal X[:,j,k]$ with the pairs $j,k$ in lexicographical order?

Comment: Also, can't you just write a similar associated kernel? Say,
$$
A_{i,j} = \sum_{k,j} \mathcal X_{i,k,l}C_{k,j}B_{l,j},
$$
with $k$ from $1$ to $N$ and $l$ from $1$ to $M$?

Comment: The [Commutator matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix) $\,\left(K^{(m,n)}\,\right)\,$ used for reversing the Kronecker $(\otimes)$ product of vectors, will also reverse a Khatri-Rao $(\boxtimes)$ product 
$$K^{(n,m)}\;(B\boxtimes C) = (C\boxtimes B)$$
This result is straightforward if one interprets the KR product as a column-wise Kronecker product.

Comment: @BenGrossmann yes, $\mathcal{X}_{(1)}$ has $L$ rows and $M*N$ columns. The mapping of elements from $\mathcal{X}$ to $\mathcal{X}_{(1)}$ is really well illustrated in https://www.kolda.net/publication/TensorReview.pdf (page 6). As far as the associated kernel for the 'reverse' khatri-rao-matricized tensor product, the summation you provided will not work because the rows of $C$ ($N$) are not equal to the associated dimension of mode 2 of $\mathcal{X}$ ($M$).

Comment: @pigtowndandy That does look helpful. Could you edit your question to add in that code so that it's correctly formatted? I'm not sure how familiar you are with markdown but you can just paste the code in, highlight it, and press the `{}` button to format it

Comment: @pigtowndandy Regarding my kernel, I think it works if the indices on $\mathcal X$ are reversed, i.e. $A_{i,j} = \sum_{k,j} \mathcal X_{i,l,k}C_{k,j}B_{l,j},$

Comment: @greg "Column-wise Kronecker product" is a great explanation, I had never heard that

Comment: @BenGrossmann Yes, will edit question - thank you for the markdown tip! The second kernel you provided is equivalent to the 'forward' kernel in my original post (this was my initial thought as well).

Comment: @pigtowndandy That makes sense, thanks for clarifying